# Web Element retrieval using inner Web Element attribute in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="Happy">  --->1
    <p class="desc">
    <p>
</div>
<div class="Happy"> --->2
    <p class="asc">
    </p>
</desc>
```

How can I get the second WebElement in selenium

Comment: Use the [1] index to get the 2nd element of happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the element by xpath like below:

```
//div[@class='Happy' and .//p[@class='asc']]
```

Get the inner by `.getAttribute("innerHTML")`.

Then, you can split the result using new line `.split("\n")`, and it seem like the target is available at the first index:

```
String str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Happy' and .//p[@class='asc']]")).getAttribute("innerHTML").split("\n")[0];
System.out.println(str);
```